# SWIFT Longitude and latitude from GoogleAutocomplete save in Firestore as nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to save longitude and latitude to Firestore from GoogleAutocomlete but it saves as 0. I am able to save name and address successfully from the textfileds but not longitude and latitude. I am new developer and I am having trouble passing the data.

This the class where I initialized address, longitude and latitude.

```
  class VendorLocation: NSObject, Codable {
    var address: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    
    
    init(address: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double){
        self.address = address
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        
    }
    
    convenience override init() {
        self.init(address: "", latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    }
    
}
```

This is the ViewController setting up the table view for each location chosen. Once tapped on the cell with the chosen location, it goes to the next view controller.

````
class LocationListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var editBarButton: UIToolbar!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    
    var vendorLocations: [VendorLocation] = []
    var selectedLocationIndex = 0
    var vendorLocation: VendorLocation!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        
    }
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail"{
            let destination = segue.destination as! SpotDetailViewController
            let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            destination.vendorLocation = vendorLocations[selectedIndexPath.row]
            
            
            selectedLocationIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
            // vendorLocations[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row]
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
        
        
        // Display the autocomplete view controller.
        present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func editBarButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if tableView.isEditing{
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
            sender.title = "Edit"
            addBarButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
            sender.title = "Done"
            addBarButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    

}

extension LocationListViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return vendorLocations.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = vendorLocations[indexPath.row].address
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Lat: \(vendorLocations[indexPath.row].latitude), Long::\(vendorLocations[indexPath.row].longitude)"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            vendorLocations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath){
        let itemToMove = vendorLocations[sourceIndexPath.row]
        vendorLocations.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        vendorLocations.insert(itemToMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        
    }
    
}

extension LocationListViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {
    
    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place ID: \(place.placeID)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        
        let newLocation = VendorLocation(address: place.formattedAddress ?? "unknown place", latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        vendorLocations.append(newLocation)
        tableView.reloadData()
        
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    // User canceled the operation.
    func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }
    
    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
    
}

```swift

This is the ViewController from where the name and address are saved to Firestore successfully but longitude and latitude are saved as zero.

```swift
class SpotDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addressTextField: UITextField!
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    var vendorLocation: VendorLocation!
    var vendorLocations: [VendorLocation] = []
    var vendorAddress: String!
    
    
    //retrurn zero
    var lat = VendorLocation().latitude.self
    var long = VendorLocation().longitude.self
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if vendorLocation == nil{
            vendorLocation = VendorLocation()
            
        }
        
        updateUserInterface()
    }
    
    func updateUserInterface () {
        addressTextField.text = vendorLocation.address
        
    }
    
    func updateFomInterface() {
        
        vendorLocation.address = addressTextField.text ?? "No address"
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destination as! LocationListViewController
        destination.vendorLocations = vendorLocations
        
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindFromLocationListViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let source = segue.source as! LocationListViewController
        vendorLocations = source.vendorLocations
        vendorLocation = vendorLocations[source.selectedLocationIndex]
        updateUserInterface()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func saveLocationButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        updateFomInterface()
        
        if let currentuser = (auth.currentUser?.uid), let vendorName = nameTextField.text, let vendorAddress = addressTextField.text {
            db.collection("Vendor").document(currentuser).collection("Locations").addDocument(data: ["name": vendorName, "address": vendorAddress, "latiude": lat, "longtitude": long]) { (error) in
                if let e = error {
                    print("For some reason the data can not be saved to the cloud! \(e)")
                } else {
                    print ("The data was saved successfully!")
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
````

Comment: Delete the lat and long properties and use vendorLocation instead. And try to keep your questions shorter and more to the point by only including relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no sense:

```
    //retrurn zero
    var lat = VendorLocation().latitude.self
    var long = VendorLocation().longitude.self
```

The construct `VendorLocation()` invokes the initializer of `VendorLocation` to create a new VendorLocation, which will not have a valid address, latitude, or longitude.